# Interrupt Python infinite while loop with key press

Tags: python, infinite-loop

I'm writing a simple script to prevent my computer from falling asleep (don't have admin privileges), and it centers around an infinite loop caused by a "while True" line:

```
import time, win32api
cursorX = 0
cursorY = 0
while True:
    cursorX, cursorY = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    time.sleep(600)
    cursorX = cursorX + 10
    win32api.SetCursorPos((cursorX,cursorY))
    cursorX, cursorY = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    time.sleep(600)
    cursorX = cursorX - 10
    win32api.SetCursorPos((cursorX,cursorY))
```

Now, I can interrupt this with a simple Ctrl + C, but I'd like to kill it more cleanly than that. Is there a simple way to write a condition to wait for a key press to kill the loop? I'm guessing it might involve an event, about which I know little.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way to clean up the use of CTRL-C is to use try-except to catch the KeyboardInterrupt like:

```
try:
    while True:
        ...
        ...
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    exit
```

Answer (score 3):

The last three lines I added will allow you to break out of the loop with any key being pressed. Dont forget the import of msvcrt

```
import time, win32api
import msvcrt
cursorX = 0
cursorY = 0
while True:
    cursorX, cursorY = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    time.sleep(600)
    cursorX = cursorX + 10
    win32api.SetCursorPos((cursorX,cursorY))
    cursorX, cursorY = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    time.sleep(600)
    cursorX = cursorX - 10
    win32api.SetCursorPos((cursorX,cursorY))
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        if ord(msvcrt.getch()) != None:
            break
```

Comment: This isn't very portable; it wouldn't work with non-windows machines!

Comment: Agreed, but none of this code would work on non-windows machines as it relies on the win32api