# Problems with keyboard key to stop reading serial data using pyserial

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am relatively new to using pyserial to talk to a microcontroller. I send a string and the microcontroller interprets and responds back.  I have a condition where I want the python script to only read data and then exit that state if a keyboard key is pressed and go back to the send data and read data state (the other while loop). The read, microcontroller response and the continuous read function is working properly, however, the program is not able to exit the while loop if the key is pressed. Is there something fundamental that I am doing wrong?
Thank you.

```
sP = serial.Serial( port = COM10, baudrate = 9600 , bytesize = 8 )

while True:
        sendData = raw_input('Enter Data')
        sP.write(sendData.encode())
        time.sleep(1)
        data = sP.readline().decode('utf-8')[:-2]
        print(data.decode("utf-8"))
        if(sendData[0]=='1'):
            print("entering loop")
            while True:
                if keyboard.is_pressed("e"):
                    print("program exiting loop")
                    sendData =('22')
                    sP.write(sendData.encode())
                    break
                data = sP.readline().decode('utf-8')[:-2]
                print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: You may break the inner loop, but what is supposed to stop the outer loop?

Comment: Also, have you tried `while not keyboard.is_pressed("e")`?

Comment: Hi, I tried using this, the program will execute the _break_ command only if I keep pressing 'e' multiple times. My guess is that the e needs to be pressed at a very specific time to be understood by the program. I am not sure how to get around that problem. Thanks.

Comment: You could use `while input() != "e"`, but then you need to press enter to get `sP.write()` to run

Comment: Yes, that will work, but I need the sP.write() to run indefinitely till a keyboard stroke is entered. Could  a temporary variable be updated to be compared to an 'e' in case a keyboard stroke 'e' is entered? But I am not sure how to bypass that if I am not entering any keystroke.

Comment: The main problem is that `keyboard.is_pressed` doesn't block. It either is/isn't pressed, and the code moves on, as fast as it can (thousands/millions of events per second), which is why you'd need to hold down the key so the condition gets met... I think a better solution is [catching KeyboardInterrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25331184/2308683)